# Android/Java. Как добавлять / удалять фрагменты в Scrollview?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-scrollview, scrollview

Добавляю по клику на кнопкe фрагменты (`new fragment`) в `scrollview`.. Каждому фрагменту присваиваю тэг `scrollview.getchildcount()`, т.е. на единицу увеличиваю...

Но проблема в том, что, когда начинаю удалять в разброс фрагменты, то получается несоответствие: было 1234, удалил фрагмент с тэгом 2, и стало 134; но тройка теперь стоит на 2м индексе в `scrollview getchildcount()`!

Как можно поправить алгоритм, чтобы фрагменты добавлялись и удалялись нормально??

Comment: судя по описанию, все работает так, как и должно. Непонятно, что значит ваше *чтобы фрагменты добавлялись и удалялись нормально*

Comment: Автор имел ввиду, чтобы при удалении фрагмента во 2 позиции удалялся фрагмент из 2 позиции, а не из 3 или т.п.

Comment: Да, да, изначально у меня тэг фрагмента равен номеру его позиции в скролвьюве! то есть позиция0 - тэг фрага0, поз1 тэг1 и тд.. но когда в разброс удаляю это нарушается.. вот как придумать не могу переделать..

Comment: а покажите то, как вы удаляете фрагменты, возможно вам необходимо пересмотреть своё решение

Comment: Удаляю так view.getTag() где вью это кнопка в фрагменте.. ей присваиваю в тэг номер позиции.. т.е. тэг кнопки совпадает с тэгом фрага и = номером позиции в скролвью.. А вот как при клике на кнопке расположенной в фрагменте получить позицию в которой находится фрагмент в скролвьюве?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы удаляете по индексу, а не по позиции. Когда вы добавляете фрагменты каждому из них присваивается свой индекс, они не будут изменяться, даже если вы их удаляете, т.е. Удаленик 2 из набора 1234 приведёт к 134, это норма, но изменятся позиции, были 1234, станет 123, где 2 с индексом 3, а 4 с индексом 3. Работайте с позициями и всё будет удаляться "Нормально".

Хотел ещё добавить, что, если ваши методы будут высоко нагружены, т.е. каждый фрагмент будет содержать большое количество данных, то ваша задумка может сильно нагрузить систему, в таком случае идеальным выходом будет использование ViewPager, в нём можно задать количество фрагментов одновременно загруженных в память, остальные же будут "Висеть" и подгрузяться, когда вы к ним будете адресовываться, также можете наследоваться от адаптера и написать свой адаптер и сделать список из фрагментов.

Почитайте этот урок: startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/… Там описано создание своего Adapter-а, так вот, чтобы реализовать удаление по нажатию на кнопку, вы можете в методе getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) добавить обработчик для вашей кнопки и по нажатию на эту кнопку сделать parent.removeView(convertView); Только не забудьте обновить список методом notifyDataSetChanger();

Comment: А вот как при клике на кнопке расположенной в фрагменте получить позицию в которой находится фрагмент в скролвьюве?

Comment: Если вы будете реализовывать через ViewPager, то у него можно получить текущую позицию, есть для этого метод **ViewPager.getCurrentItem()**, если это лист с адаптером, то можно прицепить слушатель, который будет возвращать нажатую позицию в списке, но у вас немного другой случай, данный метод среагирует при нажатии на сам элемент списка, я бы вам рекомендовал, раз уж так нужно удалять элемент, то прицепить это не к кнопке, а к самому элементу списка, в данном случае к фрагменту и можно было бы обрабатывать долгое нажатие на элемент списка и там точно также получать номер позиции и удалять

Comment: Только добавьте контекстное меню, в котором было бы поле "удалить"

Comment: Вот урок про контекстное меню:http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/47-urok-15-kontekstnoe-menju.html   Урок про события в ListView: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/85-urok-44-sobytija-v-listview.html  Урок про адаптеры: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/99-urok-47-obzor-adapterov.html

Comment: Нее, у меня все строго (дизайн + тз) никаких контекстных меню и пр.. должен быть скролвью (он просто для прокрутки вниз/вверх) и фрагменты с кнопками в нем. Я думаю может заменить скролвью на гридвью, но там можно ли сделать подобное? и удалять/добавлять? больше вариантов не знаю пока..

Comment: Рас у вас ТЗ, то может не стоит делать кучу фрагментов? Если вам нужно скролить, то лучше ScrollView

Comment: В тз точно не указывается скол и кридвью.. но это точно должно скролиться. может нужно как то через inflate и addview добавлять?

Comment: забудьте про inflate и addView, всё это может сделать Adapter без лишнего мусора, почитайте уроки выше про адаптеры, создайте свой и вы сможете реализовать вашу задумку даже с удалением по нажатию на кнопку, я вчера как-то не вспомнил про это, но сейчас придумал для вас решение лучше, но при условии, что вы будете использовать Adapter-ы и ListView

Comment: А в ListView можно вообще фрагменты добавлять?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вы можете написать 1 **layout** для всех элементов списка, а в **Adapter-е** в методе **GetView()** добавлять **Fragment** в **Layout**